# kafka broker port are differenet in server.properties but executed in same port

Tags: apache-kafka

i try to use more then one broker in kafka, but after runing the first one id=1 in port 9093 for example, and then run the second broker id=0 in port 9092,the first one is shut down and the second uses the port 9093.

serve.properties

```
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

#
# This configuration file is intended for use in ZK-based mode, where Apache ZooKeeper is required.
# See kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults
#

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0
delete.topic.enable = true

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. If not configured, the host name will be equal to the value of
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName(), with PLAINTEXT listener name, and port 9092.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE
#listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
log.dirs=/tmp/broker0
```

server_1.properties

```
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

#
# This configuration file is intended for use in ZK-based mode, where Apache ZooKeeper is required.
# See kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults
#

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=1

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################


listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093
log.dirs=/tmp/broker1
```

use more than one brokers in kafka in differents ports, i hot this error:

first broker:
[2023-12-22 03:31:35,058] WARN [Controller id=1, targetBrokerId=0] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-12-22 03:31:35,058] INFO [Controller id=1, targetBrokerId=0] Client requested connection close from node 0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

second broker:
[2023-12-22 03:31:35,110] INFO Kafka version: 3.5.1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-12-22 03:31:35,111] INFO Kafka commitId: 2c6fb6c54472e90a (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-12-22 03:31:35,111] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1703212295107 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-12-22 03:31:35,112] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-12-22 03:31:35,244] INFO [zk-broker-0-to-controller-alter-partition-channel-manager]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use node localhost:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
[2023-12-22 03:31:35,279] INFO [zk-broker-0-to-controller-forwarding-channel-manager]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use node localhost:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)

Comment: You're missing a CONTROLLER listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing the CONTROLLER listener